# Find mean or standard deviation of zip tuples

Tags: python

I am able to fine % change for element of list.

```
>>> data = [10 , 11 , 12, 13 , 20]
>>> zip(data, data[1:])
[(10, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 20)]
>>> [round (100.0 * a1 / a2 - 100 , 2 ) for a1, a2 in zip(data[1:], data)]
[10.0, 9.09, 8.33, 53.85]
```

Is it possible to find mean and standard deviation of these tuples in same pythonic way? 
Example mean of tuple (10,11) = 10.5

Comment: for mean: `data = [10 , 11 , 12, 13 , 20]
mean = [sum(x)/2.0 for x in zip(data, data[1:])]

print(mean)`

Comment: np.mean and np.std work just fine.
`    mean = [np.mean(x) for x in zip(data, data[1:])] `
`    std= [np.std(x) for x in zip(data, data[1:])]`

What you need std on two items for is a mistery to me

Comment: You want standard deviation across rows or columns?

Comment: @MartinBoyanov this question isn't tagged with `numpy`, as such, you should probably stick with the standard-library `statistics.mean` and `statistics.stdev`